# If htm or html page doesnt exist then check if aspx page exists

Tags: asp.net, redirect, global-asax

I have moved my website from using .htm/.html pages to aspx pages. Some existing websites/bookmarks etc will be referencing the old files instead of the aspx files so i want them to be sent to the aspx version (i have kept the same naming). I dont want to add redirect code on each page.

How can i do this once?

Cheers

Comment: What web server are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using IIS, then have a look at [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), which will give you the ability to easily convert all requests for .html into .aspx

Comment: there isnt something in the global.asax which i can check if its a 404 error, if its a htm or html page check if the aspx page exists and if it does redirect to it? im not sure on how i can code that up

Comment: also i dont have access to iis

Comment: @Gazza, have a look at HttpHandlers that HatSoft talks about in his answers, that looks like the way forward for you. If you don't have access to IIS, then you have very few options

Answer (score 0):

Update after comments from OP:

If you want to catch errors in the Global.asax.cs then please do it this way

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context= HttpContext.Current;

    Exception exception = context.Server.GetLastError();

    int httpCode = ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode();
    if (httpCode == 404)
    {
      ctx.Server.RedirectPermanent("~/yournewfilename.aspx", true);
     //For more infor on RedirectPermanent got to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd322042.aspx
    }
}
```

============ Else ==============

If you want something off the shelf then http://www.isapirewrite.com/ or URL Rewrite

But you can also achieve this by code, writing you own httphandler by implementing the IHttpHanlder interface for incoming request and in your case it is quite simple if a request for .htm or .html then redirect to .aspx

useful links if you decide to write your own HttpHandler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(v=vs.85).aspx

http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2006/05/25/httphandlers-%E2%80%93-learn-them-use-them/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABoilerplateHttpHandler.aspx

Comment: there isnt something in the global.asax which i can check if its a 404 error, if its a htm or html page check if the aspx page exists and if it does redirect to it? im not sure on how i can code that up. also i dont have access to iis